# Filter Questions for all Favorite Tags

Tags: support, tags

Is there a way to filter the questions, here on Web Applications or elsewhere on Stack Exchange, on all available favorite tags and not just one in particular?

These are mine: [prefs Jacob Jan](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/29140)

If this is made possible, then we're able to filter out those questions must easier !!

**UPDATE**
Can we make such a filter here on Web Apps?

PS: Is this something we can handle via Web Apps or do we need to go elsewhere for this?

Answer (score 3):

You can go to http://stackexchange.com/ and create a filter

[image: Filter]

Comment: I was hoping that it would be possible here on Web Apps. Is _that_ possible?